# How can I detect url change in address bar in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop an extension, which can detect what I typed words in address bar. If the words match something, it will show the specified url in address bar.

Actually, it's like as Google Chrome did by itself. But I will let the browser detect my keyword firstly, and show the specified url. Only when can't match my keywords, then show the url google provided.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it matches exactly what you need, but you can have a look at the [Omnibox API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html):

> When the user enters your extension's keyword, the user starts interacting solely with your extension. Each keystroke is sent to your extension, and you can provide suggestions in response.
>
> The suggestions can be richly formatted in a variety of ways. When the user accepts a suggestion, your extension is notified and can take action.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisP , I nearly give up, and you give me a wish. I will have a try, and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but you could create your own address bar in HTML and monitor it for changes.

When users type a keyword, you could modify the window.location in another window. You could also modify the same window to show the url contents in an IFrame for instance.